# Asp.net - Streaming videos with HTML5 player- Multiple video chunks as single video

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, video, streaming

I'm using a foreach to insert between video files to play for streaming, however only works for the first video

```
 public async void WriteToStream(Stream outputStream, HttpContent content, TransportContext context)
    {
        foreach (VideoInfo video in _videos)
        {
            var buffer = new byte[1024];
            bool cancel = false;
            int bytes;
            int copiedBytes = 0;
            using (Stream source = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                while (!cancel && (bytes = source.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                {

                    await outputStream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, bytes);
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your `using` is inside the `foreach` loop, the response stream is closed and disposed after the first video has been sent.

I would suggest to put the `using` around the `foreach`. Also, I wonder if the video headers will mess up things, since you keep sending every time again.

Comment: Thank you for your attention..I realized that if a video has 5 min and comes to an end and the stream keeps sending him does not continue to run the video next video to be sent

Comment: Do you have any questions left? Not sure how to read your comment.

Comment: Sorry, I think I confused when writing Comments.
My current code is like http://pastebin.com/FeJV8mWH, However only works with a video.